# does running redis-cli with --rdb block the redis instance?

Tags: redis

i have a couple of redis instances which are running RDB mode.
currently if i want to backup my instances i run BGSAVE command and copy the rdb file.
i want to get the rdb file on a remote machine so i searched for a solution and saw that redis-cli can use the --rdb option to transfer the rdb file. i am unclear about a couple of things
1: will the `redis-cli --rdb HOST > temp.rdb` command create a new RDB or will it just transfer the last RDB file created by BGSAVE?
2: will it block the redis instance similar to the SAVE command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i ran some tests and here is the answer:
it will only transfer the last rdb file created by bgsave so you have to run bgsave before transfering your file if you want it to be recent
it wont block the redis instance as i ran the command and at the same time was able to do SET commands on the instance